# How to change ANDROID Emulator UUID?

Tags: android, adb, appium

For an App testing project I need to change the Android UUID in runtime.

**Conditions** : This should be done without installing any outside APK.

**Prefered** : Changing UUID by command line. Like `adb shell`

I am not able to find answer of my question on Google.

Regards,

*Frustrated*

Answer (score 0):

*Just Restart the emulator Device to change its UUID*

OR

Uncheck **Enable ADB Integration** by going to *Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integratio*n and check it again

Answer (score 0):

emulator -avd "avd-name" -qemu -uuid "your own uuid"

Example:-

```
emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_28 -qemu -uuid 070ded79-fbd0-xxxx-xxxx-1c3405c63292
```